# Why edittext taking Text but i specified input type is textpassword?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

This is `XML` design I am using but in `EditText` i have specified `input type= text password` but while testing it is showing text how to solve this problem

thank in advance..

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_line_edittext">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eT_password_LA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: XML seems fine...may be you are setting Edittext inputtype dynamically(In Activity)

Comment: Can you remove the hint and try again. There was a bug in android regarding this.

Comment: But i need hint..how to set hint

Comment: @AbhishekS share you activity code also may be you are setting Edittext inputtype dynamically(In Activity)

Comment: mPassword = findViewById(R.id.eT_password_LA);
mPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

Comment: now i added this setTransformation method got ans. thank you all guys

Answer (score 1):

change `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to `android:background="@null"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eT_password_LA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly , you are looking for password in digits .

Use `android:inputType="numberPassword"`

Hope it Helps !!